# How to post an image to a Facebook wall using Grails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using the grails facebook-sdk plugin to connect and post to facebook.

To publish a message to a user's wall I use:

```
def publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/feed", [message:"RestFB test"])
```

This works fine, but I want to post an image to a specific album of the user. The documentation says that it should work with:

```
def publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publishFile("me/photos", [message, "Test cat"], "/cat.png")
```

But I alway get a "File not found" error. The image I have is stored in a data base and can be retrieved by getting the url to the image.

Knowing the url of the image, how can I post this image to a specific user photo album? How can I create a new Album?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the facebook-sdk but I would assume that the issue is that it can't find the file '/cat.png' relative to the location of you're project. You'll need to provide valid and accessible file path.

You could confirm this by doing something like this before publishFile...

```
assert new File("/cat.png").exists(), "File does not exist!"
```

UPDATE:

Here is an example of converting a url to a file.  **This may not be the ideal solution** if there are other options besides using an actual file.

```
    def someUrl = "http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif";
    def file = File.createTempFile("facebookUpload",".temp").withOutputStream { out ->
        out << new URL(someUrl).openStream()
    }

    file.deleteOnExit();
    def publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publishFile("me/photos", [message, "Test cat"], file)
```

Comment: I have an url to an image like: http://www.mydomain.com/234234 If I enter it in the browser it shows the image. But how can I convert the to a File, such that the publish() method does accept it?

Comment: i updated my answer.  Again, keep in mind i haven't worked with the fb-sdk and this is untested code.

Comment: This does not really solve my problem. I want to know how can I publish an image to a user's facebook wall and to a users album in Grails?

Comment: To publish to wall, you just need to post to `/userid/photos` – to upload to a specific album, you have to get the album id first, and then post to `albumid/photos`; but whereas the former requires only `publish_stream` permission, the latter will require `user_photos`. And if you don’t want to do a file upload, you can also upload the photo by giving a (publicly reachable) HTTP URL to the image, using the parameter name `url`. This is all in the docs btw., https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: @confile, i'm trying to post message. could u please post ur config & BuildConfig file and controllers and views. sorry for greedy demands.